# I created rules with multiple ASNs, correct?

Tags: php, selenium, asn.1

I'm learning PHP and developing a project. Is the code below correct?
What I'm trying to do is this:
The if block will work if an ASN information containing "telecom" is accessed.
If an ASN other than "Telecom" comes in, the else block should work.

```php
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']; 
$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$hata = array();  
$api   = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ip-api.com/json/{$ip}"));
$ulke   = $api->isp;

use Facebook\Webdriver;

if( preg_match("/telekom/i", $ulke))
{

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub';
$proxyUrl = 'xx.xx.xx.xx:50100';

$capabilities = new Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities(
    [
        Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\WebDriverCapabilityType::BROWSER_NAME => 'chrome',
        Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\WebDriverCapabilityType::PROXY => [
            'proxyType' => 'manual',
            'httpProxy' => $proxyUrl,
            'sslProxy' => $proxyUrl,
        ],
    ]);
$driver = Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities);
$driver->get("https://xxxx.com");
$driver->manage()->window()->maximize();
sleep(1);
$page_source = $driver->getPageSource();
echo '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">';
echo $page_source;
$driver->quit();
}
else { 
$url = "https://xxxxx.com";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//for debug only!
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $resp;
exit;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure, that the api what you are using is working? Oh, yes, it is, just my browser redirected to https.

Comment: I want to know this.
Is there an error here?
Can it do exactly what I want it to do? Do you think there is any mistake?

Comment: Yes, but provide much simpler code snippet. `<?php
$api   = json_decode('{"isp":"some isp telekom"}');
$ulke   = $api->isp;

if( preg_match("/telekom/i", $ulke))
{
 print("telekom found in isp field");
}`

Comment: For example, does it correctly query an ASN information that comes as "turk telekom communication services"?
Is your "telecom" knowledge correct? .

Is there a possibility to jump to the ELSE Block? I want to understand this.

Comment: Yes, you don't have to use real query, you can construct your own json object (look the sample that i provided), just delete telekom from the sample json, and add an else block and it should work az expected.